# prettify.js not highlighting my code

Tags: html, pretty-print

I was trying to use `prettify.js` to higlight my html code. Here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Making Quines Prettier</title>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js?autoload=true&amp;skin=sunburst&amp;lang=HTML" defer="defer"></script>
<style>.operative { font-weight: bold; border:1px solid yellow }</style>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Language hints can be put in XML application directive style comments. -->

<pre class="prettyprint">
<h1>Making Quines Prettier</h1>
<h1>Making Quines Prettier</h1>
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

What I am expecting it just show

```
<h1>Making Quines Prettier</h1>
<h1>Making Quines Prettier</h1>
```

but its rendering HTML code and displaying output as:

## Making Quines Prettier

## Making Quines Prettier

Comment: It's currently looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/4v46ukho/ what is your expected output?

Comment: it should show `<h1>Making Quines Prettier</h1>
<h1>Making Quines Prettier</h1>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to escape the content so that they are **not** rendered as html tags

so the code would be written as

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
    &lt;h1&gt;Making Quines Prettier&lt;/h1&gt;
    &lt;h1&gt;Making Quines Prettier&lt;/h1&gt;
</pre>
```

See the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/s1ckfbsj/1/

**EDIT**

If you really want to write html and have it rendered, here's an option:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<pre class="prettyprint">
    <h1>Making Quines Prettier</h1>
    <h1>Making Quines Prettier</h1>
</pre>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.prettyprint').each(function() {
            var $self = $(this);
            var html = $self.html();
            $self.text(html);
        });
    });
</script>
```

See the second example here: http://jsfiddle.net/s1ckfbsj/2/

Comment: so prettify doesn't do that part itself ?

Comment: Exactly - prettify does not handle escaping for you.

Comment: then it will be a complicated one

Comment: yes, generally html inside a `pre` tag is not accepted

Comment: @Manish, I updated the answer with a version for using HTML inside the `pre` tag, see example here: http://jsfiddle.net/s1ckfbsj/2/